# !empty function wont work on login using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

This is my login form

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/checkAdmin')?>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Signin</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And my controller

```
public function checkAdmin()
{
    $data['aEmail'] = $this->input->post('email', true);
    $data['aPassword'] = $this->input->post('password', true);

    if (!empty($data['aEmail']) && !empty($data['aPassword'])) 
    {   
        echo 'working';
    } 
    else
    {
        echo 'not working'; 

    }

}
```

Whether I key in values or not, it still echos 'not working'. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Controller Code:-**

```
class admin extends CI_Controller {

 function login()
    {
        $email= $this->input->post("email");
   $password = $this->input->post("password");  

 $result = $this->db->get_where('table_name',array('email'=>$email,'password'=>$password))->row_array();
            if ($result >0) //active user record is present
            {

                 
                $url = base_url('admin/Admin/dashboard');
                redirect($url);    
            }
            else{
                 redirect('admin/Admin');

            }
        }
        
}
```